# How can I use environment specific variables in micronaut?

Tags: kotlin, micronaut

I'm new to micronaut and server side programming in general. The micronaut documentation, unfortunately, does not make a lot of sense to me, as I do not have a Java background. A lot of the terms like "ApplicationContext" make sense in english, but I have no idea how to use them in practice.

Trying to start with a very basic app that prints different configurations ("localhost", "dev", "prod") depending on the environment it is in.

Here's my controller

```
@Controller("/")
class EnvironmentController {

    // this should return "localhost", "DEV", "PROD" depending on the environment
    @Get("/env")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    fun env() = "???" // what should I put here ?

    // this should return the correct mongodb connection string for the environment
    @Get("/mongo")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    fun mongo() = "???" // what should I put here ?
}
```

Here's the `application.yml`. Ideally I'd have 1 yml file for each environment

```
micronaut:
  application:
    name: myApp
  server:
    port: 8090

environment: localhost

mongodb:
  uri: 'mongodb://localhost:27017'
```

`Application.kt` is untouched with the rest of the files generated by the `mn` cli tool. How can I set per environment parameters, or pass the yml file as a parameter when starting micronaut?

Are there any conventions around this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can specify an environment with `-Dmicronaut.environments`, or by specifying them in the context builder `Micronaut.run` in your Application class.

https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#environments

Then for example `application-env.yml` will be loaded.

https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#propertySource

The docs are pretty clear on this

Comment: Hi thanks for the pointing me to the docs. I did read that section but it didn't really sink in. I finally got it to work by specifying `-Dmicronaut.environments`. It wasn't clear that that *was* the system property (don't have much Java experience). I still have no idea how to use the application context though. The generated `main()` does `Micronaut.build()...` which doesn't allow me to specify environments.

Comment: The build method https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/api/io/micronaut/runtime/Micronaut.html#build-java.lang.String...- returns an instance of `Micronaut` which has an environments method https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/api/io/micronaut/runtime/Micronaut.html#environments-java.lang.String...-

Answer (score 2):

By default Micronaut only looks for application.yml. Then, for tests,dev and prod, it loads application.yml and overrides any values there with the ones defined in application-test.yml, application-dev.yml and application-prod.yml
If you want to enable any other environment, you need to do it manually

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Micronaut.build(args)
             .mainClass(Application.class)
             .defaultEnvironments("dev")
             .start();
}
```

https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#_default_environment

Answer (score 0):

To be able to use environment specific variables in controllers and other classes., we have to inject them into fields.

Property values can be loaded with the `@Value`, `@Property` or `@ConfigurationProperties` annotations.

```
@Property(name='app.message', defaultValue = 'unknown')    
private String message

@Property(name='env.test', defaultValue = 'env.test not set')
private String envt

@Property(name='env.dev', defaultValue = 'env.dev not set')
private String envd
```

Assuming that `app.message` is defined in both dev and test environments, it is loaded from the property source that is defined last. (For instance, in `MICRONAUT_ENVIRONMENTS=dev,test` test is defined last and takes precedence.)

If `env.test` is defined in the test environment, it is loaded from the `application-test.properties` property source. Likewise, the `env.dev` is loaded from `application-dev.properties`.

Also note that the default environment set by the application builder's `defaultEnvironments` method is only applied when *no other active environments are detected*. Otherwise, the default environment is ignored.

Comment: I believe this question is about Kotlin :-)